# scrollrect moves with object - help?

Tags: actionscript-3

I got a serious problem here: I have a scrolling background that is 1320 x 1000 big. I'm using a sprite as a container where my background canvas is placed inside of it. Additionally I add (via addChild) a score sprite inside of the background sprite (the one that holds the bg canvas so the score appears on top of the bg canvas).

The goal is that when I add a score it shall be stuck to the background (even when the scrollrect moves; it shall have a fixed position on the background).

The problem is that this doesn't work because when the score appears it moves with the scrollrect and this is not what I want. I already tried it with globalToLocal but had no success yet. Probably because I don't really understand globalToLocal (and vice versa). Please can anyone help me out with this problem? Thanks in advance.

These are some code excerpts:

```
private var backgroundBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1320, 1000, false, 0x000000);
private var canvasBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1320, 1000, false, 0x000000);

private var canvasBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasBitmapData);
private var canvasRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 660, 500);

private var backgroundSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

backgroundSprite.scrollRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 660, 500);
canvasBitmap.scrollRect = new Rectangle(330, 250, 660, 500);

backgroundSprite.addChild(canvasBitmap);
backgroundSprite.cacheAsBitmap = true;

addChild(backgroundSprite);


tempScoreText = new ScoreTextField(String(10), textFormat, oldAstX, oldAstY, 20);
scoreTexts.push(tempScoreText);
backgroundSprite.addChild(tempScoreText);
```

Comment: How are you moving your clips around? It seems like all the code you mentioned is fine (although I'm somewhat confused on this, so I may be mistaken).

Comment: Hope this helps (these codes are just excerpts):

`player.update(stage.mouseX + canvasBitmap.scrollRect.x, stage.mouseY + canvasBitmap.scrollRect.y, plDelay, step);`

Code 2:

`canvasRect.x = player.x - 330;
canvasRect.y = player.y - 250;
if (canvasRect.x < 0) canvasRect.x = 0;
if (canvasRect.y < 0) canvasRect.y = 0;
if (canvasRect.x > 659) canvasRect.x = 659;
if (canvasRect.y > 499) canvasRect.y = 499;
canvasBitmap.scrollRect = canvasRect;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a *sample* together to see if I could see what you're experiencing, but I don't think I'm seeing the same thing because this example seems to work like it's supposed to. Here's my *example*:

```
var backgroundBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1320, 1000, false, 0x000000);
var canvasBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1320, 1000, false, 0xff0000);

var canvasBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasBitmapData);
var canvasRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 660, 500);

var backgroundSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

backgroundSprite.scrollRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 660, 500);
canvasBitmap.scrollRect = new Rectangle(330, 250, 660, 500);

backgroundSprite.addChild(canvasBitmap);
backgroundSprite.cacheAsBitmap = true;

addChild(backgroundSprite);

var tempScoreText = new TextField();
tempScoreText.text = "temp score";
backgroundSprite.addChild(tempScoreText);

this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function(event):void {
    backgroundSprite.scrollRect.x = mouseX;
    backgroundSprite.scrollRect.y = mouseY;
});
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, maybe you could upload a **swf** for me so that I could see what you see? Perhaps a *SOF chat* is in order as well. I've been stuck before and **people have helped me out** so this is just me paying it forward.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try that asap and will let you know if that's gonna work.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the item to scroll with scroll rect:

```
stage.addChild(item)
```

If you want the item to be sticky, then only use

```
addChild(item)
```

and use

```
root.scrollRect
```